# Luminance histogram calculation in GPU-android opengl es 3.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-3.0

For Luminace histogram calculation

I have used the code from the project GPU image ios by Brad Larson.

He has used blending for Histogram calculation.

Attaching the Vertex and Fragment shader

Vertex shader

```
#version 300 es 
in vec4 position;
out vec3 colorFactor;
const vec3 W = vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114);
void main() 
  {
      float luminance = dot(position.xyz, W);
      colorFactor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (luminance *  0.00784313725), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      gl_PointSize = 1.0;
   } ;
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 300 es 
const lowp float scalingFactor = 1.0 / 256.0;
in lowp vec3 colorFactor;
out vec4 gl_FragColor;\n"+
void main() 
  {
     gl_FragColor = vec4(colorFactor * scalingFactor , 1.0);
  };
```

i have used a 256x1 texture attached to an FBO and Pass in the pixel as input to vertex shader.
Texture is defined as follows

```
GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_NEAREST);
GLES30.glTexParameterf(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);

GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA,
                256, 1, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA,
                GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
```

And my onDrawFrame goes like this

```
GLES30.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GLES30.glBlendEquation(GLES30.GL_FUNC_ADD);
GLES30.glBlendFunc(GLES30.GL_ONE, GLES30.GL_ONE);
GLES30.glEnable(GLES30.GL_BLEND);

filterPositionAttribute = mshader2.getHandle("position");


GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(filterPositionAttribute, 4, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,false,60, PixelBuffer);
GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(filterPositionAttribute);


GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_POINTS, 0, mViewportWidth * mViewportHeight /16);
```

i will be using 1 pixel out of 16 for histogram calculation.

Now i am getting the graph and values.
But when verified using matlab and other software like irfanview ,it appears deviated.

Attaching the graph created in excel 
[values from my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnt9U.png)

[verified values using matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcbOR.png)

is this variation expected or i am making some mistakes.
Could anybody help ,thanks in advance

Comment: Where does your "60" comes from ? That makes it once every 15 pixels and not every 16 pixels.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest to add 0.5 to make sure your draw the GL_POINT in the middle of the pixel. Also, the constant should be 1 / 256.0 and not 1 / 255.0. `gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (0.5 + luminance) * (1.0 / 256.0), 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: @246tNt Thanks for the suggestion,but even after using gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (0.5 + luminance) * (1.0 / 256.0), 0.5, 0.0, 1.0); i am getting variation when compared with the calculation in matlab

Comment: Are you sure of the format of you "PixelBuffer" ?

Comment: PixelBuffer is a bytebuffer and i am getting the pixels by using GLES30.glReadPixels(0, 0, mViewportWidth, mViewportHeight, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, PixelBuffer);              This pixel i feed into the vertex shader

Comment: Mmmm, I don't see anything wrong. I implemented a similar histogram just last weekend and it worked as expected. Are you sure of the matlab reference ? (from the histogram it just looks like a gray image ?). Also, as a side note, you don't need colorFactor at all, you can remove it completely.

Comment: Did you do a `glViewport(0, 0, 256, 1)` before rendering ?

Comment: yes, i have used that GLES30.glViewport(0, 0, 256, 1);

Comment: For your histogram calculation,did you consider every pixel for histogram calculation?

Comment: Yes, I used all my input data in my application. And you should fix your 60 into 64 btw if you want every 16 pixels.

Comment: you did this in android?                                                                             did you use a 16 bit texture?

Comment: No this was on desktop OpenGL but using the same algorithm principles. Although now that you mention it, I'm using a floating point R32F texture for the result and not a GL_RGBA one. Because in a single byte you can only store up to 255 "hits" in a single bin, which might not be enough for your image.

Comment: can i use R32F in opengl es 3.0 ,in that case i can consider every pixels in my image.

Comment: Looks like R32F is not "color renderable" in OpenGL ES. But R32UI is. So you could use that to allow for a much wider range.

Comment: (As a note to my previous comment, if you have GL_EXT_color_buffer_float you can use R32F as a render target)

Comment: For using R32UI i should change only GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA,
                256, 1, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA,
                GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null); wrt?  and how to get back the result using glreadpixel

Comment: @246tNt Could you share the portion of your histogram calculation code that does the R32F part (32bit red component).i am having issues when trying to change it to 32 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using C and desktop GL, but here's the gist of it :

Vertex shader

```c
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec2 inPosition;
void main()
{
    int x = compute the bin (0 to 255) from inPosition;

    gl_Position = vec4(
        -1.0 + ((x + 0.5) / 128.0),
        0.5,
        0.0,
        1.0
    );
}
```

Fragment shader

```c
#version 330
out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
    outputColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Init:

```c
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32F, 256, 1);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0);
```

Drawing :

```c
/* Upload data */
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, num_input_data * 2 * sizeof(float), input_data_ptr, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

/* Clear buffer */
const float zero[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, zero);

/* Init viewport */
glViewport(0, 0, 256, 1);

/* Draw */
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, num_input_data);
```

For brievety I only put the init code for the resulting buffer, all the VBO/VAO init/binding has been skipped

Comment: can i use glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32F, 256, 1);  in opengles 3.0 ,i have been using glTeximage2d.Also how to verify the result using glreadpixel

Comment: Seem to exist : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES30.html#glTexStorage2D%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29  . As for the readback : `glReadPixels(0, 0, 256, 1, GL_RED,  GL_FLOAT, buffer)`  should work.

Comment: i had verified that my device supports GL_EXT_COLOR_BUFFER_FLOAT.  so right now my code is GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA32F,
                    256, 1, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA,
                    GLES30.GL_FLOAT, null);                                                 and the corresponding glreadpixel is  GLES30.glReadPixels(0, 0, 256, 1, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, PixelBufferTest);                  where PixelBufferTest is   ByteBuffer PixelBufferTest = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 16 * 256 * 1); but still not working. Any idea?

Comment: 32 bit texture is working fine,i had used  GL_R32F for storing histogram count.
so now i consider every pixel for histogram calculation.
But even now when i compare with the histogram calculation done in irfanview or some other software, it appears deviated.
ie total number pixel count in each bin is different.
Do u have any other suggestion?

Comment: Well are you sure they use the same weighting ( W ) coefficients than you do ?  They also might consider color space ( sRGB ) or things like that ... do it yourself on the CPU in plain C as a reference and that should match your GPU impl.

Comment: I cant understand how does your code works