# Calculate histogram in OPENGL

Tags: c++, opengl, histogram

I try to calculate histogram of a image, using OPENGL. I have read some post about that but I still get error. My histogram buffer always return zeros.
Some post which I have read:

[Maknoll Histogram](https://github.com/maknoll/GPU/blob/master/exercise06/Histogram)

[Luminance histogram calculation in GPU-android opengl es 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539335/luminance-histogram-calculation-in-gpu-android-opengl-es-3-0)

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;
#include <SOIL.h>

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource = "\n"
"#version 330 core\n"
"attribute vec3 inPosition;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    float x = inPosition.x;\n"
"\n"
"    gl_Position = vec4(\n"
"        -1.0 + ((x) * 0.0078125),\n"
"        -1,\n"
"        0.0,\n"
"        1.0\n"
"    );\n"
"}\n";

const GLchar* fragmentSource = "\n"
"#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 outputColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    outputColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";

void CheckStatus(GLuint obj)
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
    std::vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
    std::cerr << &log[0] << std::endl;
    exit( -1 );
}

GLfloat buffer[256];
GLuint hist[256];
float _image[512*512*3];

int main()
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("sample_gray.bmp", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    unsigned char image_gray[width * height];
    printf("%d\t%d\n", width, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        image_gray[i] = image[i * 3];
        _image[i * 3] = image[i * 3];
        _image[i * 3 + 1] = image[i * 3 + 1];
        _image[i * 3 + 2] = image[i * 3 + 2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        hist[image_gray[i]]++;
    }

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Basic", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    GLuint num_input_data = width * height;

    /* Upload data */
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, num_input_data * sizeof(float) * 3, _image, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vertexShader, fragmentShader, shaderProgram;
    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    CheckStatus(vertexShader);
    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    CheckStatus(fragmentShader);
    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outputColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);


    CheckStatus(shaderProgram);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "inPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    GLuint tex;
    GLuint fbo;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    // glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32F, 256, 1);
    // glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0);

    /* Clear buffer */
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    /* Init viewport */
    glViewport(0, 0, 256, 1);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    /* Draw */
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, num_input_data);


    glReadPixels(0, 0, 256, 1, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\t%f\t%d\n", i, buffer[i], hist[i]);
    }

}
```

Could anybody help me,thanks in advance.

I have updated my code, it's working now :D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;
#include <SOIL.h>

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource = "\n"
"#version 330 core\n"
"in vec3 inPosition;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    float x = inPosition.x;\n"
"\n"
"    gl_Position = vec4(\n"
"        -1.0 + ((x + 1) * 0.0078125),\n"
"        0.0,\n"
"        0.0,\n"
"        1.0\n"
"    );\n"
"}\n";

const GLchar* fragmentSource = "\n"
"#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 outputColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    outputColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";

void CheckStatus(GLuint obj)
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
    std::vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
    std::cerr << &log[0] << std::endl;
    exit( -1 );
}

void _check_gl_error(int line) 
{
    GLenum err (glGetError());

    while(err!=GL_NO_ERROR) 
    {
        std::string error;

        switch(err) 
        {
            case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:      error="INVALID_OPERATION";      break;
            case GL_INVALID_ENUM:           error="INVALID_ENUM";           break;
            case GL_INVALID_VALUE:          error="INVALID_VALUE";          break;
            case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:          error="OUT_OF_MEMORY";          break;
            case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:  error="INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION";  break;
        }

        std::cerr << "GL_" << error.c_str() <<":"<<line<<std::endl;
        err=glGetError();
    }
}

GLfloat buffer[256];
GLuint hist[256];
float _image[512*512*3];

int main()
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("sample_gray.bmp", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    unsigned char* image_gray = new unsigned char[width * height];

    printf("%d\t%d\n", width, height);


    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        image_gray[i] = image[i * 3];
        _image[i * 3] = image[i * 3];
        _image[i * 3 + 1] = image[i * 3 + 1];
        _image[i * 3 + 2] = image[i * 3 + 2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        hist[image_gray[i]]++;
    }

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Basic", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    _check_gl_error(__LINE__);
    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    GLuint num_input_data = width * height;

    /* Upload data */
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, num_input_data * sizeof(float) * 3, _image, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vertexShader, fragmentShader, shaderProgram;
    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    CheckStatus(vertexShader);
    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    CheckStatus(fragmentShader);
    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outputColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);


    CheckStatus(shaderProgram);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "inPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    GLuint tex;
    GLuint fbo;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, 256, 1, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32F, 256, 1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    _check_gl_error(__LINE__);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    /* Clear buffer */
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    _check_gl_error(__LINE__);


    /* Init viewport */
    glViewport(0, 0, 256, 1);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    /* Draw */
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, num_input_data);


    glReadPixels(0, 0, 256, 1, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, buffer);
    _check_gl_error(__LINE__);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\t%f\t%d\n", i, buffer[i], hist[i]);
    }
    free(image_gray);
}
```

Special thank to @Vallentin for your enthusiasm!

Comment: First thing I see is that you bind `fbo` before you generate it. Second: Your `CheckStatus` method only works if there are no shader object and shader program with the same id. All handles are just unsigned integers and it is perfectly valid for a OpenGL implementation to give you a shader object 0 and a shader program object 0. In that case your method would query both, link status and compile status.

Comment: @BDL, Thank you. I updated my code below. Can u help me check it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My histogram buffer always return zeros.

Interesting. Because I don't know which compiler that let's something like this fly by:

```
int width, height;
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("sample_gray.bmp", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
unsigned char image_gray[width * height];
```

Where you'd need to do:

```
unsigned char *image_gray = new unsigned char[width * height];
```

*Remember to later free the memory `delete[] image_gray`.*

Your shader also doesn't compile or maybe your driver is a bit more lean than mine. As given `#version 330 core` you can't use `attribute` and would have to use `in`.

```
in vec3 inPosition;
```

As is `CheckStatus()` also tells this:

```
0(3) : error C7555: 'attribute' is deprecated, use 'in/out' instead
```

You're also trying to bind a framebuffer you don't even have yet.

```
GLuint fbo;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
[...]
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
```

You'd need to flip that around:

```
GLuint fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
```

*It also puzzles me why your compiler would let that slide, as MSVC screams at me.*

```
Error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'fbo'
```

You're also not binding the texture before applying any changes to it.

```
// glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

So uncomment that `glBindTexture()` call.

You're also not creating any vertex arrays. Which checking `glGetError()` would have told.

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

Do so before calling `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`.

Also your clear color is red. So that's not going to help you that much. As now your call to `glReadPixels()` would only yield `1.0`.

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Now `glReadPixels()` still only yield zero. However unbinding or not creating the framebuffer at all. Then it gives what I assume is the desired result. Since not using the framebuffer shouldn't be so, I'm suspecting that there's something wrong with it. I can't however seem to pin point it by glancing over your code. But as the code is riddled with problems already, this is a fair starting point.

Additional:

- You're targeting OpenGL 3.3 while `glTexStorage2D()` is core in 4.2. Point being, that if you want to make sure `glTexStorage2D()` is supported, target 4.2.
- The call to `glActiveTexture()` is redundant.
- Since your texture has a height of 1, consider using a 1D texture.
- Remember to check `glGetError()` or better yet utilize [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output)

---

**Edit**

First of all You can't call `_check_gl_error()` before having created the window (and context) and called `glewInit()`.

Instead of manually adding the line number you could use `__LINE__`. Thus `_check_gl_error(__LINE__)`.

Again don't use a red clear color. Use a black clear color `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. As blending `1.0` and say `0.1` results in `1.1`, which is clamped back to `1.0`. Thus the red color channel should be `0.0` from the get-go.

I realized the problem. In your vertex shader you're manually setting `y` to `-1.0`. This ends up falling out of the screen, given that you're drawing `GL_POINTS`.
Setting it to `y` to `-0.9999` seems to give the desired result now. However relying on this is like playing with fire.

If you now run the application you'll now see a mixture of `0.0` and `1.0`. The reason you get `1.0` is because in your fragment shader you're setting `outputColor` for the red channel as `1.0`. Again summing all those might be some crazy value, but in the end it'll get clamped back down to `1.0`.

Instead try with:

```
outputColor = vec4(0.005, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Now you should see the output increasing and decreasing, instead of being either `0.0` or `1.0`. However note that if `hist[i]` is greater than 200, then any that are so will result in `1.0`. Because `1 / 0.005 = 200`.

Everything is at least *working* now.

Comment: Thank for reply @Vallentin. I have updated my code with points you recommend. I add `_check_gl_error` function using `glGeterror()` to check error. However, my buffer still return zeros (1.0 if i clear color to red, as you said). Can you check my code again? Thank you. One more thing, Can you sugget  me replace function `glTexStorage1D` to other function?

Comment: Thank you very much @Vallentin. It's working now :)) Although I need fix a bit in your answer, it is very helpful. It help me a lot. Thank you again.